# DragSortListView Changing position in source list

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop

How can I change the actual position of the item in my actual source list 
when dragging and droping item using [DragSortListView.](http://bauerca.github.io/drag-sort-listview/reference/com/mobeta/android/dslv/DragSortController.html)

Comment: Modify the backing dataset by swapping elements. If you add some code of what you already have or tried, we could potentially steer you in the right direction. As it is, your question is rather vague in the sense that you don't reference the actual library you're using (there may be several) or show a minimal understanding of the problem by including some code/description of your attempts to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I am using http://bauerca.github.io/drag-sort-listview/reference/com/mobeta/android/dslv/DragSortController.html